# ERROR in Internal Error: The structure of the program changed during codegen

Tags: angular, webpack

We're getting strange error while trying to migrate our project to Angular 5 + Webpack 4:

> ERROR in Internal Error: The structure of the program changed during codegen

Seems it occures inside Angular compiler. Does anyone have any experience with it?

Comment: is it while using angular-cli's `ng serve` ?

Comment: @David Not exactly. We're not using CLI in this project since we need more customized build. Everything was fine under Angular 4 + Webpack 2. And fails after upgrade. It is after calling `./node_modules/.bin/webpack-cli`

Comment: I'm working around this by commenting out this line: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/b807106f54e1fa7228f90c01488537f845b65598/packages/compiler-cli/src/transformers/program.ts#L729

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, in my case it was solved by upgrading dependency:

`"@angular-devkit/core": "0.4.2"` --> `"@angular-devkit/core": "0.5.5"`

Answer (score -1):

In my case, similar to Yuriy K., i upgraded a different dependancy:

`"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.11.0",` -> 
`"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.12.2",`